# How does one update Python through the terminal on WinSCP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, winscp

I am trying to run a script which involves numpy through the terminal on WinSCP, but whenever I do, I get the following error:

---

import gensim

File "/data/work/worker/gensim/**init**.py", line 5, in

from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, summarization, utils  # noqa:F401

File "/data/work/worker/gensim/parsing/**init**.py", line 4, in

from .preprocessing import (remove_stopwords, strip_punctuation, strip_punctuation2,  # noqa:F401

File "/data/work/worker/gensim/parsing/preprocessing.py", line 42, in

from gensim import utils

File "/data/work/worker/gensim/utils.py", line 38, in

import numpy as np

File "/data/work/worker/numpy/**init**.py", line 142, in

from . import core

File "/data/work/worker/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 50, in

raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

```
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
```

Please note and check the following:

- The Python version is: Python2.7 from "/usr/bin/python"
- The NumPy version is: "1.18.5"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named _multiarray_umath>

---

I suspect that the issue is that the version of Python being quoted here is outdated; however, after having done some searching, I cannot find any literature on how to update Python on WinSCP. I have Python 3.8 installed on my machine, and I have tried moving the installer and the .exe file into the WinSCP directory to no avail. Is there any way to update python directly in the terminal? Alternately, is this issue actually nothing to do with a stale version of Python at all?